# How to handle CouchDB deleted documents with replications

Tags: couchdb, purge, compact-database

Using v.3.1.1 CouchDB.  We are replicating a database to many clients.  We are deleting many documents on the server.  Is it suggested following be run on some kind of schedule (daily maybe):

- https://{database_url}/{database}/_compact
- https://{database_url}/{database}/_compact/{design_document}
- https://{database_url}/{database}/_view_cleanup

I understand we can create a filter and replication document to ignore deleted documents.  Is this needed when compacting and cleaning up?

Alternatively, can purge be run instead or in addition to compact/cleanup?

- https://{database_url}/{database}/_purge

Should we consider upgrading CouchDB version in the event new features were introduced?

I am trying to be mindful of deletions and replications.